# load viewcontroller within a tabbar control

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

on viewdidload of one of my tabbar viewcontrollers I'll like to display or popup another view controller. here's my code

```
 if (_history.count == 0) {

    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"emptyHistorySegue" sender:self];
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    MSAEmptyHistoryViewController *popupController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EmptyHistoryViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:popupController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The load the viewcontroller on top of the tabview controller. I need this view to display but still allow the user to see the tabbar buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will run into problems if you try to transition to another view controller in `viewDidLoad`. You should either switch the child view controllers of the tab bar controller or you can present a subview within one of the child view controllers.

Comment: I'll give this a shot now

Answer (score 0):

When -viewDidLoad is called, the view controller is generally not presented. As such, if you try to present another controller, it will crash.

Try -viewDidAppear: if you want what you are describing.

Comment: tried this with the same result the viewcontroller loads on top of everything